# Are "move" operations logged?

Tags: bitcoin-core-accounts, movecmd, logging

Are "move" operations logged somewhere in the wallet or somewhere else?

If so, can the "move history" be retrieved, and how?

edit: apparently the command `listtransactions` lists some `move` operations, but not all, and I have no clue if there is some criteria, or it is simply bugged.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make a move operation that doesn't get logged such that listtransactions doesn't list it?  I've been unable to.

Comment: @ChrisMoore now that I know that it is really supposed to be logged, I'll investigate, thanks ;)

Comment: Found out the problem was I didn't know `listtransactions` defaulted to showing only 10, I assumed the default was "all".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all move operations add an accounting entry to the wallet. If `listtransactions` doesn't show the move, this is most likely to be a problem with `listtransactions`.

Answer (score 0):

So you are basically asking whether the debug.log file mentions (records) move operations in general regardless of whether they involve transactions?

If so you can probably answer better than I by searching your debug.log file, as I have never actually done any move operations so would not expect to find any mentioned in my debug.log

The debug.log would be where I would look them up if they are being logged though.

I don't see any obvious logging calls in the movecmd routine the RPC call calls, which is in rpcwallet.cpp so it doesn't look as if it does make a log entry.

However it does make a debit entry call and a credit entry call to the wallet, so the wallet should know about the move unless for soem weird reason it is deliberately forgetting about moves that do not cause actual transactions. These entries include the comment you put in the RPC call so it does not seem right to forget them since having the user put in a comment and not remembering their comment seems kind of pointless.

It would take more digging to check if maybe its something like "if there is no comment nor any actual transaction forget about it" but if so maybe always including a comment might help make sure a record is kept.

I guess only someone intimate with that part of the code knows the full nitty gritty details of how it decides what to remember. Maybe only the GUI actually gives you access to these accounting records.

Your term "logged" maybe threw me off course as it looks like maybe it is recorded in the accounting system in the wallet but not "logged" in the actual debug.log file.